# Prevent ActiveAdmin Logins with Pundit Policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, pundit

I have ActiveAdmin and Pundit setup and working.  My User model has a role attribute (rails 4.1 enum).  How can I only allow a user with the admin role to log into /admin?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this, without touching `ActiveAdmin::BaseController`.

In your AA initializer, add

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.on_unauthorized_access = :user_not_authorized
```

And implement `ApplicationController#user_not_authorized`

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
:
def user_not_authorized(exception)
  sign_out # or user will end up in a redirection loop
  flash[:error] = "Access has been denied because ..."
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

Finally, update the policy for AA pages (or dashboards, or whatever)

```
# app/policies/active_admin/page_policy.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class PagePolicy < ::ActiveAdminPolicy
    def show?
      User.roles[user.role] >= User.roles['manager']
    end
  end
end
```

Done, only managers and above will be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, here is how I solved it:

Roles are defined in `User#role`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [ :client, :reseller, :manager, :admin, :super ]
end
```

Here's how to restrict access to AA's `/admin` all together for users who are clients or resellers.

First, add a `before_filter` to AA's `BaseController`, as described [here](http://viget.com/extend/8-insanely-useful-activeadmin-customizations).

```
# lib/active_admin/deny_unprivileged/usage.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  ##
  # Only users showing a minimum user level (role)
  # should be allowed to access the administration interface.
  module DenyUnprivilegedUsage
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_filter :deny_unprivileged_usage
    end

    private

    ##
    # Deny access to /admin, unless user is, at least, a manager.
    #
    # This does the same as Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_out_and_redirect,
    # but adds a flash message explaining why access has been denied.
    #
    # See Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_out_and_redirect
    def deny_unprivileged_usage
      if current_user and not User.roles[current_user.role] >= User.roles['manager']
        resource_or_scope = current_user
        scope = ::Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
        redirect_path = new_user_session_path
        ::Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(scope)
        flash[:error] = "!!!"
        redirect_to redirect_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Create an initializer.

```
# config/initializers/active_admin_extensions.rb
require 'active_admin/deny_unprivileged_usage'
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.send(:include, ActiveAdmin::DenyUnprivilegedUsage)
```

Restart your server.

Now, a user who is not at least a manager will be denied access to `/admin`. The user will actually login successfully, however, after login, the filter defined above will sign out the user right away and redirect back to the login page.

The `deny_unprivileged_usage` method is almost a copy of `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_out_and_redirect` - except that it adds a flash message, explaining to the user why login has been denied. Without this change, the user would only get back to the login page, not knowing why login has been denied.

**Update**

On second thought, if a user is registered, it is hard to imagine that they should never be able to login.

Thus, maybe it would be cleaner to implement role-based access restrictions using different authorization adapters and policies for different namespaces. As described [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md).

Then, `/reseller` would be able to login and, say, change their password, while `/manager` would be presented with much more functionality. This way, policies and AA resources would be clearly separated.